# CursorLoader can only be used to database that system built-in or with ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

Google suggest android developers use [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) and [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) to load data from database,but `CursorLoader` must have a Uri parameter to construct it.The uri maybe like contact item:`content://contact/people/1`,and it have a `ContentProvider` to respond it and operate the data.Does we can only use the CursorLoader in built-in database,or must create our own `ContentProvider` to parse the uri we defined and operate the data.Simply to say,can we use it in our own database without creating a corresponding ContentProvider?

Comment: *can we just use it ... without ... ContentProvider?* no... search for some "auto contentprovider" library ... fx: long time ago I create somthing like this ... http://selvin.pl/AutoContent.zip ... or try this => https://github.com/hamsterksu/Android-AnnotatedSQL

Comment: @Selvin,thanks for your library code,I will look at a moment.I wish that you can explain your thinking briefly as an answer so that others can learn from it.

Comment: can we just use it (LoaderManager) ... without ... ContentProvider? yes.. see [here](https://gist.github.com/casidiablo/1217628)